# irreducible monic polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

Let $P_1,P_2,\dots $ be the irreducible monic polynomials in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$. Is there any possibility to prove the following

$$\lim_{n\to \infty } \sum_{i_1+\cdots+i_n=t}z^{i_1\deg P_1 + \dots +i_n\deg P_n} = (pz)^t $$ for $t\in \mathbb{N}$ and $\vert z \vert < 1/p$?

Comment: (I didn't tag this complex-analysis) Actually it comes from the following (same precondition as above) I have to prove: $\prod_{r=1}^{\infty }(1+z^{\deg P_r}+z^{2\deg P_r}+\cdots ) = 1+pz+p^2z^2+p^3z^3+\cdots $

Comment: Yes, the user who edited your question tagged it complex-analysis. Note that Your question and your comment are not compatible. According the the comment, you need to show $$\sum_{i_1\deg P_1+\dotsc i_n\deg P_n = t}z^{i_1\deg P_1+\dotsc+ i_n\deg P_n} = (pz)^t$$ for $n$ large enough that $\deg P_r > t$ for all $r > n$. If you de-expand the geometric series, you'd get to prove $\prod_{r=1}^\infty (1-z^{\deg P_r}) = 1-pz$, which might be simpler. Assume that $\deg P_r \leqslant \deg P_{r+1}$ for all $r$. Then it's an exercise in combinatorics, if you know how many $P_r$ of each degree there are.

Comment: The goal of the whole session (where this is a piece of) is to prove Gauss' formula for the number of monic irreducible polynomials over a finite field, so I don't know how many $P_r$ of each degree there are...

Comment: And actually I think you are wrong with your sum, I think it's for all $i_1,\dots , i_n$ with $\sum i_k=t$, since with each factor $\sum_m (z^{\deg P_k})^m$ you get with the Cauchy product (or convolution) that the sum of the $m's$ have to sum up to your coefficient index...

Comment: I was wrong with the idea that it might be easier to do with the de-expanded geometric sums, but not with the constraint for the $i_k$. Wait a moment for an answer.

Comment: @user26857 I didn't remove it because I wasn't sure whether the tag was inappropriate. That I don't see the reason for a tag doesn't mean there isn't a sensible reason for adding a tag. My comment wasn't meant as a criticism, just an inquiry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment you write

> I have to prove:  $$\prod_{r=1}^{\infty }(1+z^{\deg P_r}+z^{2\deg P_r}+\cdots ) = 1+pz+p^2z^2+p^3z^3+\cdots$$

Since there are only finitely many polynomials of degree $\leqslant n$ in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$, for every fixed power of $z$, only finitely many factors of the infinite product are relevant, hence we need not occupy ourselves with convergence issues.

Now, the coefficient of $z^t$ on the right hand side is $p^t$, which is the number of monic polynomials in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$. On the left hand side, the coefficient of $z^t$ is the number of ways of writing $t$ in the form

$$\sum_{k=1}^n i_k\cdot \deg P_k$$

where $n$ is chosen so that $\deg P_r > t$ for all $k > n$, and the $i_k$ are integers. Note that

$$\sum_{k=1}^n i_k\deg P_k = \deg \prod_{k=1}^n P_k^{i_k},$$

so the coefficient of $z^t$ on the left hand side counts the number of factorisations of monic polynomials of degree $t$ into powers of the $P_k$. Since $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ is a unique factorisation domain, we have a bijection between the monic polynomials of degree $t$ and the factorisations, hence the coefficients are the same.

Comment: Thank you! I have two questions: 1. Your very first remark: Why are only finitely many factors relevant? There are infinitely many degrees, so there are infinitely many irreducible monic polynomials aren't there? 2. I still don't know why $t=\sum i_k\deg P_k$...If we multiply the first two factors $\sum_m (z^{\deg P_r})^{m}$ ($r=1,2$) of the infinite product then we get $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty }\sum_{i+j=k}(z^{\deg P_1})^i(z^{\deg P_2})^j=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty }\sum_{i+j=k}(z^{i \deg P_1+j\deg P_2})$

Comment: For all factors $(1 + z^{\deg P_r} + z^{2\deg P_r} + \dotsc)$ with $\deg P_r > t$, if you take the $z^{k\deg P_r}$ term from the sum with $k > 0$, that alone gives you an exponent of $z$ larger than $t$, so from all these factors, you must pick the $1$ to get a $z^t$ in the product, the other terms only contribute to the coefficients of higher powers. Ad 2., if you group the factors by $i+j = k$, then if $\deg P_1 \neq \deg P_2$ the exponents of $z$ in the inner sum aren't equal. If you compute the Cauchy-product directly by the formula, you must fill in the missing powers, and write

Comment: $$1 + z^{\deg P_r} + z^{2\deg P_r} + \dotsc = \sum_{m=0}^\infty a_{r,m}\cdot z^m,$$ where $$a_{r,m} = \begin{cases} 1 &, m = k\cdot \deg P_r \text{ for some } k\in\mathbb{N} \\ 0 &, \text{ otherwise}.\end{cases}$$ Then the product of the first two sums becomes $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\sum_{j=0}^k a_{1,j}\cdot a_{2,k-j}\right)z^k.$$

Comment: Thank you! I think I got it!